# Androd Studio Schedule a method at specific time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working with android studio - java.
In the last two days i have searched a lot and didn't find an answer.
I want to schedule a method once time, even if the app is closed or phone is locked.
I have tried with Alarm manager and it doesn't work when i close the app.
I tried JobScheduler and it requires Internet, my method doesn't requires Internet.
I tried to create a background service but i don't know how to call the stop method after X time and when the service stops call the method i want.
X time - the user pick a time to schedule with timepicker and when it finish i want to execute my method.
Please can someone help me?

Comment: Someone has an answer?